# Please use a gs:// URL for your Firebase Storage bucket

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have project which is connected to multiple firebase projects. I can access first firebase project storage, I can access second firebase project database, but I can't access second firebase project storage. Here is my code:

```
private void configureFirebase(String projectID, String applicationID, String APIkey, String databaseURL, String storageBucket) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(projectID)
            .setApplicationId(applicationID)
            .setApiKey(APIkey)
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseURL)
            .setStorageBucket("gs://myProjectID.appspot.com")
            .build();

    try {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "secondary");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
    }

    FirebaseApp secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
    FirebaseDatabase otherDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondary);

    databaseReference = otherDatabase.getReference();

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("secondary");
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(storageBucket);

    saveBucketUrl(storageBucket);
}
```

And here is the error which I am getting:

```
Please use a gs:// URL for your Firebase Storage bucket
```

Even if I have proper URL for Storage, something is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of initialization via the Firebase SDK, you should actually remove the "gs://" from the name of the bucket.

```
setStorageBucket("myProjectID.appspot.com")
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. Although I've done what you said, the problem is still there. It throws same message, "Please use a gs:// for your Firebase Storage bucket.

Comment: If the SDK isn't working the way you expect, I suggest contacting Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore